# Xrm.Page object hierarchy

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, msdn, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I am going to understand the `Xrm.Page object hierarchy` , that has 3 objects in it.

**1.** Context

**2.** Data

**3.** UI

Yes! Good. But in the given diagram [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328474.aspx) , Some child objects are blue while some are white. Is it specific reason for that? Why they are of different color? Are these Objects or Collections or something else?
Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White denotes objects. Blue denotes [collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481592.aspx).

Let’s take 2 examples.

To get `id` property of entity record, have to use `getId()` method of entity object.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()
```

> `Xrm.Page.data.entity` provides methods to retrieve information
>   specific to the record displayed on the page, the save method, and a
>   collection of all the attributes included in the form.

To get all the child attributes of entity record, entity object gives attributes collection. Pass the name & get the particular attribute properties.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(arg).getAttributeType()
```

> The `Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes` collection provides access to
>   each entity attribute that is available on the form.

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute` is the shortcut for accessing `Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes` collections.

Comment: Thanks @Arun. I also figured that, the word `s` with the collection names are telling that there are more than one. e.g. `Stages`,`attributes`, `Controls`, `Steps`. Take it another way, One entity can have multiple `attributes` or one `attribute` contains multiple `controls`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best way to work with the CRM Web Client Model, is to use this cheat sheet.  Its from 2015, but will be very applicable for everything up to 9.

http://crmunwrapped.blogspot.com/2015/03/crm-2015-client-api-cheat-sheet.html